# Wipe everything from the screen and display image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with all sorts of Views in it (buttons, text etc).
What I'd like to do is programatically wipe EVERYTHING in it and then set some picture to the background. That of course using the same activity without switching to a different one.
Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to wipe everything you can use:

```
ViewGroup.removeAllViews();
```

on your root view in the layout.

But you might want to consider using a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) or simply hiding the content using

```
View.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

instead to be able to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

All your views must be in some main layout (if not, put them in one such layout). Give that layout an id, then use findViewById() to get that layout, and call the [removeAllViews()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews%28%29) or the removeAllViewsInLayout() method on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all your Views in a single layout and set the layout's visibility to View.GONE and set image visibility to visible

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to actually remove views. Use `ViewSwitcher` instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ViewSwitcher
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewswitcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <!-- your views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

then, in your code:

```
ViewSwitcher vs = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewswitcher);
vs.showNext();
vs.showPrevious();
```